# Linq Query for getting details from 2 table and putting into ObservableCollection C#

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

Currently i am creating users collection and binding to data grid using following code. It's working Fine.

```
  private ObservableCollection<User> users; 

  using (CarStudioDBEntities dt = new CarStudioDBEntities())
  {
    var catList = (from user in dt.Users
                   select user).ToList();
                   users = new ObservableCollection<User>(catList);
                   this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                   {
                       lstUsers.ItemsSource = users;
                   });
  }
```

xaml

```
<DataGrid x:Name="lstUsers"  Background="White"  Margin="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="80"> 
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                       <DataTemplate>
                             <Button Name="viewUserDetailsBtn" Content="View" Click="viewUserDetailsBtn_Click" Background="#FF3F5164" BorderBrush="Black" FontSize="10" Height="24" Padding="0" Margin="0" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                 </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Username" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Username}"/>
   <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
   <DataGridTextColumn Header="Role" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Role}"/>
   <DataGridTextColumn Header="Contact Number" Width="*" Binding="{Binding ContactNo}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Status}" />
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
```

Problem is That i need to create another ObservableCollection parts;
which contain foreign Key reference to Category Table.
Now i need to get Category Name which is in Category Table through categoryId present in parts,
and finally bind details of parts with category Name To Data Grid.
i am not able to write proper linq query for this and.
In Short i need ObservableCollection with Details Of Parts And Category Together.

Comment: There is no point creating an observable collection from a static list. This is not going to give you collection updates on the original query.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a inner join on DataTables using LINQ.

```
var result = from dataRows1 in table1.AsEnumerable()
             join dataRows2 in table2.AsEnumerable()
             on dataRows1.Field<string>("ID") equals dataRows2.Field<string>("ID")

             select dtResult.LoadDataRow(new object[]
             {
                dataRows1.Field<string>("ID"),
                dataRows1.Field<string>("name"),
                dataRows2.Field<int>("<other fields you want>"),
              }, false);
result.CopyToDataTable();
```

After this you can use the new DataTable for binding